# Loading files merged with executable

Tags: c++, merge

I'm trying to merge a file with my executable, and read the merged file. I merge them with the Windows command;

```
copy /b Game.exe+Image.jpg TheGame.exe
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
std::ifstream f("Image.jpg");
if (f.good()) {
    std::cout << "Found Image.jpg" << std::endl;
}
```

`Image.jpg` is in the same directory as the resulting executable file, and it works. However when I use the command to merge them and then delete the `Image.jpg` file it is not found (although it is merged with the executable.)

Any suggestions?

Comment: WTH are you trying to achieve? Merging `.jpg` files together? That won't work from a simple approach.

Comment: Please, specify what software you're using to "merge" the resource with the executable.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - You have a typo WTH -> WTF

Comment: It's _really_ unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. You will have to _explain_ your goals. A novel concept, I know. But you can't just go "oh, I want to _merge_ this with that then _it works_ but sometimes _it is not found_". I mean, WTH does that mean?

Comment: It seems like he wants to ship just the exe file "merging" resources into the exe... Yikes

Comment: Can be done - Convert the jpg to a CPP file (i.e. an array). Compile it and build it in

Comment: Easy, GIMP can export an image to C format...

Comment: @EdHeal I prefer the slightly more _noble_ tone.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - But that is blasphemous. Hell is related to religion but ... is not (or is it?!)

Comment: @EdHeal Is `heck == hell`? You probably just misread this ;-) ...

Comment: Love2D merges zip files into the exe, and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifstream` only works with external files.  You deleted the file it is trying to open, so of course it will not find the file.  What you are attempting cannot (easily) be done using binary merges.  If you want to store a file inside of an executable, the correct approach is to store it in a resource instead.  Read the following chapter on MSDN for more information.

[Introduction to Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468900(v=vs.85).aspx)

In particular, the following example shows how go create a new resource in an .exe file and write data into it. The example copies a resource from another .exe file, but you can write whatever you want. In tbis case, replace `RT_DIALOG` with `RT_RCDATA`, and write your image data.

[Using Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of Resources!!